# Setting SpamAssassin's Bayes_path per user and dovecot

Tags: dovecot, spamassassin, sieve, spamd

I have dovecot, Spamassassin and postfix running. I started to use `sa-learn` to get better and more precise spam identification and filtering.

I have not set the `Bayes_path` preference on my `local.cf` file, thus when I call `sa-learn -u myuser@mydomain.org --spam`, the Bayes DB gets updated at `/root/.spamassassin`.

I decided then to create a sieve filter on dovecot, as described [on Dovecot's wiki page](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/howto/antispam_with_sieve/). Basically, Dovecot's sieve plugin execute `sa-learn` with a `-u` argument, apparently the same way I do when I use it manually.

BUT, the thing is that when Dovecot executes `sa-learn`, the bayes database is created on the virtual user's folder, ie., `/var/mail/vmail/mydomain.org/user/.spamassassin. When I call it manually, the db used is` /root/.spamassassin`

I am now confused as I don't know if, when evaluating spam, spamd will use the Bayes DB on the user's Maildir, or if it will use the one under /root/.spamassassin.

I would really like to have my spam evaluation done per user, not site wide, so I wonder:

- How can I configure `bayes_path` for each user, individually, on a virtual users setup?
- Does calling `spamd` with `--virtual-config-dir` have anything to do with this? I tried it, setting it up with my virtual users path, but it didn't seem to make any difference when it comes to what I describe in this post. With or without it set up, the results above are the same.

Comment: Don't call *spamassassin* as root! Some scary security issues have been revealed in the past and more are likely lurking.